# Need some recommendations on good IR hands-on training

Tags: forensics, professional-education, incident-response, incident-analysis

Does anyone know if there is any good hands-on training for incident response and digital forensics, or certification I need to take in order to gain more hands-on experience? Thanks and any helpful information is appreciated.

Comment: In the workplace or on your own time?

Comment: I guess in my own time. SANS is just too expensive -- around $5000 for each course and I am still not sure if the company will pay for me. So are there other choices? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good place to start is [Open Security Training](http://opensecuritytraining.info/Training.html). Despite the site design, they have some quality material there for you to work through.

As you noted, you'll want some hands-on experience as well. Finding challenges online can help with this. You can look at [test images](http://www.forensicfocus.com/images-and-challenges) (some will be old but still useful!) or, if you're looking more into incident response than digital forensics, the [Honeynet Challenges](https://honeynet.org/challenges) and [Malware Traffic Analysis](http://www.malware-traffic-analysis.net/index.html) exercises.

Answer (score 1):

On IronGeek (or YouTube, and free):

- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/louisvilleinfosec2015/04-memory-acquisition-in-digital-forensics-and-incident-response-jason-hale
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/derbycon2/brett-cunningham-beyond-strings-memory-analysis-during-incident-response
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/grrcon2015/bumper-massage00-security-incident-response-derek-milroy
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/derbycon3/s206-diy-forensics-when-incident-response-morphs-into-digital-forensics-john-sammons
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/bsidescleveland2012/automating-incident-response-mick-douglas
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/centralohioinfosec2015/modern-approach-to-incident-response-james-carder-and-jessica-hebenstreit
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/circlecitycon2014/215-ten-commandments-of-incident-response-for-hackers-lesley-carhart
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/derbycon4/t322-advanced-incident-response-with-bro-liam-randall-hectaman
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/bsidescleveland2012/netflow-for-incident-response-jamison-budacki
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/bsidesboston2015/205-next-gen-incident-management-building-out-a-modern-incident-management-capability-john-mcdonald
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/derbycon2/3-2-4-jamie-murdock-how-to-create-a-one-man-soc
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/circlecitycon2015/300-operationalizing-yara-chad-robertson
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/converge2015/track102-adaptive-monitoring-and-detection-for-todays-landscape-jamie-murdock
- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/securewv2015/securewv06-the-art-of-post-infection-response-and-mitigation-caleb-j-crable

On SafariBooksOnline Videos (monthly-pay access):

- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/video/networking/forensic-analysis/9780132853835
- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/video/networking/forensic-analysis/9781466695917
- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/video/networking/forensic-analysis/9781771370615
- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/video/networking/security/9781466695979

On Udemy (one-time-pay access):

- https://www.udemy.com/ifci-expert-cybercrime-investigators-course/
- https://www.udemy.com/surviving-digital-forensics-memory-analysis-1/
- https://www.udemy.com/digital-evidence-acquisition-protecting-your-case/
- https://www.udemy.com/surviving-digital-forensics-ram-extraction-fundamentals/
- https://www.udemy.com/surviving-digital-forensics-memory-analysis-2/
- https://www.udemy.com/surviving-digital-forensics-imaging-a-mac-fusion-drive/
- https://www.udemy.com/draft/94110/
- https://www.udemy.com/reconcertification/

On PluralSight (one-time-pay access or monthly):

- https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/digital-forensics-tools-kali-linux-imaging-hashing

On Lynda (through LinkedIn, one-time-pay, or monthly-pay access):

- http://www.lynda.com/Developer-tutorials/Computer-Forensics-Essential-Training/170337-2.html

Answer (score 0):

SANS training is excellent:
https://www.sans.org/course/advanced-incident-response-threat-hunting-training

Even just taking GCUX which had a 1 day IR training was very impactful.

Free blog : https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog